# Error message when trying to connect to cluster endpoint

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, dns, google-cloud-platform

When I try to connect to my Kubernetes cluster endpoint IP, I get this message. Does anybody knows where this comes from and would could be the problem here?

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/\": No policy matched.",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {

  },
  "code": 403
}
```

Comment: Is your connection proxied? This error usually means your certficates aren't valid

Comment: Hey NullDev! Thanks. I'm new to Kubernetes. Do you think it is a NGINX problem?

Comment: It's not a Nginx problem. k8s api is thinking you are anonymous user. Describe your authorization process and you will be helped

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide to many information on what you want to achieve. But as Konstantin already mentioned, this error is visible only when you try to access the API as unauthorized (anonymous) user. 
You have probably tried to `curl` the API server as an anonymous user.

You can find exact steps on how to explore the API server in this great [article.](https://medium.com/@nieldw/curling-the-kubernetes-api-server-d7675cfc398c)

> To interact with the Kubernetes API you need a ServiceAccount with the
>   correct permissions, obtained through a (Cluster)Role and a
>   RoleBinding. Authenticate by using the ServiceAccount’s token. Since
>   all communication is over TLS you also need the self-signed
>   certificate. Alternatively, allow insecure connections, but this is
>   not recommended.

More about Kubernetes API and how to access it [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#accessing-the-cluster-api).