# I have a problem with Kubernetes depoyment. Can anybody help I always get this error when trying to connect to the cluster IP

Tags: authentication, nginx, kubernetes

I have problems with Kubernetes. I try to deploy my service for two days now bu I'm doing something wrong.

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/\": No policy matched.",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {

  },
  "code": 403
}
```

Does anybody knows what the problem could be?
Here is also my yaml file:

```
# Certificate
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
 name: ${APP_NAME}
spec:
 secretName: ${APP_NAME}-cert
 dnsNames:
   - ${URL}
   - www.${URL}
 acme:
   config:
     - domains:
         - ${URL}
         - www.${URL}
       http01:
         ingressClass: nginx
 issuerRef:
   name: ${CERT_ISSUER}
   kind: ClusterIssuer

---
# Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ${APP_NAME}
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: 'true'
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: ${APP_NAME}-cert
    hosts:
    - ${URL}
    - www.${URL}
  rules:
  - host: ${URL}
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: ${APP_NAME}-service
          servicePort: 80

---
# Service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ${APP_NAME}-service
  labels:
    app: ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}
spec:
  selector:
    name: ${APP_NAME}
    app: ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: http

---
# Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ${APP_NAME}
  labels:
    app: ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}
spec:
  replicas: ${REPLICAS}
  revisionHistoryLimit: 0
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: ${APP_NAME}
        app: ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: webapp
          image: eu.gcr.io/my-site/my-site.com:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
          env:
            - name: COMMIT_SHA
              value: ${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
          livenessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 80
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          readinessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 80
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: '16Mi'
            limits:
              memory: '64Mi'
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: ${REGISTRY_PULL_SECRET}
```

Can anybody help me with this? I'm stuck and I've no idea what could be the problem. This is also my first Kubernetes project.

Comment: FWIW, don't name `Service` objects as `${APP_NAME}-service`; it just means you have to type more characters to put `-service` at the end of a command that will already contain `svc`; all of those names are namespaced twice: once per kubernetes namespace and a second time per resource type. So you can have a `Service` named `foo` and a `Deployment` named `foo` and so on.

Comment: Who build the cluster? This issue mainly shows up in self build clusters using Kelsey Hightowers Kubernetes the hard way manual (at least older version) due to missing the addition of base RBAC setup in there. If you use a deployer like kops, or just cluster-up.sh, this issue should not be there.

Comment: I've build the cluster with the Gitlab Kubernetes integration. There I disabled RBAC. So this shouldn't be a problem, right?

Answer (score 0):

> `"message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/\": No policy matched.",`

.. means just what it says: your request to the kubernetes api was not authenticated (that's the `system:anonymous` part), and your [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) configuration does not tolerate the anonymous user making any requests to the API

No one here is going to be able to help you straighten out that problem, because fixing that depends on a horrific number of variables. Perhaps ask your cluster administrator to provide you with the correct credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I have explained it in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54252274/error-message-when-trying-to-connect-to-cluster-endpoint/54257409#54257409). You will need ServiceAccount, ClusterRole and RoleBinding. You can find explanation in this [article](https://medium.com/@nieldw/curling-the-kubernetes-api-server-d7675cfc398c). Or as Matthew L Daniel mentioned in the Kubernetes documentation. 
If you still have problems, provide the method/tutorial you have used to deploy the cluster (as "Gitlab Kubernetes integration" does not tell much on the method you have used).